# Concatenation using nested streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have two lists of Strings, List categories, and List choices, and my objective is to concatenate contents of these 2 lists as-

```
List<String> categories = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Cat-1" , "Cat-2", "Cat-3"});
List<String> choices = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Choice-1" , "Choice-2", "Choice-3"});
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(categories.size() * choices.size());
for (String cat : categories) {
    for (String choice: choices) {
        result.add(cat + ':' + choice);
    }
}
```

How can I achieve it using java Streams.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a simple flat map here:

```
 categories.stream()
          .flatMap(left -> choices.stream().map(right -> left + ":" + right))
          .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: How to do the same if you have N lists where you want to append their elements with same index like here?

Comment: @ElectRocnic you mean something like; `{ [a,b], [c, d] }` and the result would be : `[a:c, b:d]`? If not, care to provide an example?

Comment: I found this solution which works fine for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44657975/3433137

Did not know that this has actually a name, namely "zip" or "zipping" lists together.