# How to zip multiple lists using java 8?

Tags: list, java-8

Given :

```
List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
List<Integer> b = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
List<Integer> c = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
List<Integer> d = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);

List<List<Integer>> sample = Arrays.asList(a,b,c,d);
```

How can I get this result with java 8?

```
[(1,1,1,1),(2,2,2,2),(3,3,3,3)]
```

Comment: such a simple operation: ***Arrays.asList(a,b,c,d)***, why do you need a stream / lambda for that?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ  if you print it, the output is `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`. he wants to sort and group by values

Comment: still the Q: why do you need a stream / lambda for that?

Comment: Have you tried something ? It seems that you are required to use the Stream API, so I would guess this is some sort of homework. Please show what you have tried first.

Comment: Early versions of Java 8 had a Stream zip method, but this was removed in later releases.

Answer (score 4):

```
/**
 * Zips lists. E.g. given [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], returns [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]].
 * @param listOfLists an N x M list
 * @returns an M x N list
 */
static <T> List<List<T>> zip(List<List<T>> listOfLists) {
    int size = listOfLists.get(0).size();
    List<List<T>> result = new ArrayList<>(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        result.add(
                listOfLists.stream()
                        .map(list -> list.get(i))
                        .collect(toList()));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer which is compact, works, and supports an unknown amount N of lists. Searched a solid hour on the web to find this. Thank you!

Comment: please tell me what I should give in@ param listOfLists an N x M list if my list are like 
List<List<String>> data1= [[fName, lName], [Easter, Bristowe], [Easter, Bristowe], [Easter, Bristowe], [Easter, Bristowe]]

List<List<String>> data2= [[email], [ebristowe0@dropbox.com], [rmacgragh1@ocn.ne.jp], [mminshaw2@time.com], [rtommen3@dot.gov]]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @GovindKumarThakur it seems that the type parameter `T` will be `List<String>` in your case; therefore, try `zip(List.of(data1, data2))` (assuming you're using Java 11+) which should return `[[[fName, lName], [email]], [[Easter, Bristowe], [ebristowe0@...]], ...]`

Answer (score 2):

Java streams don't natively support zipping.

If you want to do it manually, then using an IntStream as an 'iterator' over the lists is the way to go:

```
    List<Integer> l1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    List<Integer> l2 = Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4);

    List<Object[]> zipped = IntStream.range(0, 3).mapToObj(i -> new Object[]{l1.get(i), l2.get(i)}).collect(Collectors.toList());

    zipped.stream().forEach(i -> System.out.println(i[0] + " " + i[1]));
```

This is ugly, however, and not the 'java' way (as in using an array of 'properties' instead of a class).

Answer (score 0):

If we consider that all the Lists have the same size, so why Java 8? you can just use a simple loop like this :

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i<a.size(); i++){
    list.add(Arrays.asList(a.get(i), b.get(i), c.get(i), d.get(i)));
}
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3]]
```

---

**I really insist to read this post here [Is using Lambda expressions whenever possible in java good practice?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/341066/is-using-lambda-expressions-whenever-possible-in-java-good-practice)**

Comment: I am 100% aware that it is possible to do this with a simple loop, but my question is about achieving the same result with java 8.

Comment: @Will why do you want to use Stream API to do everything? It will be more complex than this simple solution.

Comment: Why does "using Java 8" imply "using Streams/Lambdas"? Loops are also part of Java 8.

Comment: @Will check my edit can you please read that post that i already share?

Comment: This is probably best for the simple example provided in the question but could have bad performance if you use list types that don't provide constant time for the `get` operation.

Comment: @YCF_L Thanks for your post but this question is not about debating why lambdas are bad in some cases, it's about knowing if it is possible to achieve this result with a lambda. Besides, your answer doens't reply to my question, I want to zip multiple lists, not 4.

Answer (score 0):

If i right understand your question you need something like that:

```
private <T> List<List<T>> zip(Stream<Iterable<T>> stream) {
    return stream.collect(LinkedList::new,
            (lists, ts) -> {
                if (lists.isEmpty()) {
                    ts.forEach(t -> lists.add(new LinkedList<T>() {{
                        add(t);
                    }}));
                } else {
                    Iterator<List<T>> listIterator = lists.iterator();
                    Iterator<T> elementIterator = ts.iterator();
                    while (listIterator.hasNext() && elementIterator.hasNext()) {
                        listIterator.next().add(elementIterator.next());
                    }
                    while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
                        listIterator.next();
                        listIterator.remove();
                    }
                }
            }, (lists, lists2) -> {
                Iterator<List<T>> firstListIterator = lists.iterator();
                Iterator<List<T>> secondListIterator = lists2.iterator();
                while (firstListIterator.hasNext() && secondListIterator.hasNext()) {
                    firstListIterator.next().addAll(secondListIterator.next());
                }
                while (firstListIterator.hasNext()) {
                    firstListIterator.next();
                    firstListIterator.remove();
                }
            });
}
```

And you can get desired results with

```
System.out.println(zip(sample.stream()));
```