# java list.add() is updating all the indexes

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have two `List<List<String>>` data

```
List<List<String>> data1= [[fName, lName], [Easter, Bristowe], [Easter, Bristowe], [Easter, Bristowe], [Easter, Bristowe]]

List<List<String>> data2= [[email], [ebristowe0@dropbox.com], [rmacgragh1@ocn.ne.jp], [mminshaw2@time.com], [rtommen3@dot.gov]]
```

I want to merge this list such that my final list should look like

**[[fName, lName,email], [Easter, Bristowe,ebristowe0@dropbox.com], [Easter, Bristowe,rmacgragh1@ocn.ne.jp], [Easter, Bristowe,mminshaw2@time.com], [Easter, Bristowe,rtommen3@dot.gov]]**

I tried this

```
for (int i = 0; i < data1.size(); i++) {
            List<String> list = data1.get(i); 
            List<String> email= data2.get(i);
            list.add(list.size(), email.get(0));
        }
```

After running above code I am output like this

[[fName, lName, email], [Easter, Bristowe, ebristowe0@dropbox.com], [Easter, Bristowe, ebristowe0@dropbox.com], [Easter, Bristowe, ebristowe0@dropbox.com], [Easter, Bristowe, ebristowe0@dropbox.com], [Easter, Bristowe, ebristowe0@dropbox.com], [Easter, Bristowe, ebristowe0@dropbox.com], [Easter, Bristowe, ebristowe0@dropbox.com], [Easter, Bristowe, ebristowe0@dropbox.com], [Easter, Bristowe, ebristowe0@dropbox.com], [Easter, Bristowe, ebristowe0@dropbox.com], [Raquela, MacGragh], [Malinde, Minshaw], some more data like this]

could any one please help on my problem statement.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can iterate over second list and append email to first list using second list index

Comment: @Abhishek I think that a change of the first list was not intended.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to zip multiple lists using java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653421/how-to-zip-multiple-lists-using-java-8)

Comment: The snippet that you supplied does not compile. You're trying to add email, a List<String>, into list, a List<String>. The variable list can only contain String elements. If you replace data2.get(i) by data2.get(i).get(0) probably the obtained result will be what you expect.

Comment: @RubioRic that's my typo error actually this was the .add() code
list.add(list.size(), email.get(0));
Still I am not getting the required output

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
assert data1.size() == data2.size(); // throws an exception if both lists have different lengths

final List<List<String>> resultList = new ArrayList(); // creates your final list
for (int i = 0; i < data1.size(); i++) {
    List innerList = new ArrayList(); // creates an inner list, which will later be put in your final list
    innerList.addAll(data1.get(i)); // adds everything from the ith list of data1 to innerList
    innerList.addAll(data2.get(i)); // adds everything from the ith list of data2 to innerList
    resultList.add(innerList); // adds innerList to your resultList
}
```

**Example/Explanation**

```
list1: [[Apple, Banana], [Orange, Carrot, Potato], [Melon, Coconut]]
list2: [[Mango],         [],                       [Strawberry, Raspberry]]
```

For merging 2 nested lists, both of them have to have the same size. You should assert that this is true, so that if this condition is *not fulfilled*, your app *crashes* instead of doing unexpected things.

First, a new list is being created:

```
resultList: []
```

In each iteration, an innerList is created:

```
innerList: []
```

It gets filled with all the items of list1's innerList:

```
innerList: [Apple, Banana]
```

And then with all the items of list2's innerList:

```
innerList: [Apple, Banana, Mango]
```

After that, it is added to the resultList:

```
resultList: [[Apple, Banana, Mango]]
```

This process is repeated until the resultList is filled:

```
resultList: [[Apple, Banana, Mango], [Orange, Carrot, Potato]]
resultList: [[Apple, Banana, Mango], [Orange, Carrot, Potato], [Melon, Coconut, Strawberry, Raspberry]]
```

Comment: resultList.add(innerList); is showing error 
The method add(String) in the type List<String> is not applicable for the arguments (List)
Please try this in a compiler and then post the solution Thanks.

Comment: Thanks just single modification is needed and then your code is working fine

final List<String> resultList = new ArrayList();
change this line to 
final List<List<String>> resultList = new ArrayList();

Comment: Oh sorry for the small mistake, I corrected it! Should work fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may have another typo somewhere. I've implemented a small example using your for loop and the output seems correct.

Code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class TestList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<List<String>> mainList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        createListAndRegister(mainList, "fname", "IName");
        createListAndRegister(mainList, "Easter", "Bristowe");
        createListAndRegister(mainList, "Easter", "Bristowe");
        createListAndRegister(mainList, "Easter", "Bristowe");
        
        
        List<List<String>> secondaryList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        createListAndRegister(secondaryList, "email");
        createListAndRegister(secondaryList, "ebristowe0@dropbox.com");
        createListAndRegister(secondaryList, "rmacgragh1@ocn.ne.jp");
        createListAndRegister(secondaryList, "mminshaw2@time.com");
                
        for (int i = 0; i < mainList.size(); i++) {
            List<String> mainElement      = mainList.get(i); 
            List<String> secondaryElement = secondaryList.get(i);
            mainElement.add(mainElement.size(), secondaryElement.get(0));
        } 
        
        for (int i = 0; i < mainList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(mainList.get(i));            
        }
    }

    private static void createListAndRegister(List<List<String>> list,
                                              String... elements) {
        
        List<String> aux = new ArrayList<>();
        
        if (elements != null) {
            Collections.addAll(aux, elements);
        }
        
        list.add(aux);      
    }
}
```

Output obtained - one line per list stored in mainList

```
[fname, IName, email]
[Easter, Bristowe, ebristowe0@dropbox.com]
[Easter, Bristowe, rmacgragh1@ocn.ne.jp]
[Easter, Bristowe, mminshaw2@time.com]
```

Comment: from morning I keep  trying/debugging  my code could you  please debug and tell me where I made typo. 
Thanks

Comment: @GovindKumarThakur I don't have your complete code. I can't debug what I don't have. Your for loop is correct once you have added the get(0) that I suggested above. Maybe your lists are not well-formed, they don't have the expected structure. You should debug that.